# Regarding JFileChooser

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, java.util.scanner, jfilechooser

I have developed a program that is counting the number of lines in a file that is shown below

```
Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the Drive name like C,D,E etc");
    String drive=in.next();
    System.out.println("Enter the main folder name");
    String main_folder=in.next();
    File directory=new File(drive+":"+"//"+main_folder+"//");

Map<String, Integer> result = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    //File directory = new File("C:/Test/");
    File[] files = directory.listFiles();
    for (File file : files) {
        if (file.isFile()) {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileReader(file));
            int lineCount = 0;
            try {
                for (lineCount = 0; scanner.nextLine() != null; lineCount++);
            } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
                result.put(file.getName(), lineCount);
            } }}        

    for( Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry:result.entrySet()){
          System.out.println(entry.getKey()+" ==> "+entry.getValue());
        }
```

but I was trying to add a swing interface JFilechooser , I want that user should select the particular folder and all the files inside that folder to be get selected and rest above as my code works as it is , Please advise

Please advise for desiging the jfile chooser so that I can integrate my above code.

I have design one more solution that is

```
package aa;

import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.FileDialog;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class FileBrowse extends JFrame {

private JButton browseSwing = new JButton("Choose File");
private JTextField textField = new JTextField(30);
private JButton approve = new JButton("Ok");


public FileBrowse() {
setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
setSize(600,80);
setResizable(false);

browseSwing.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        if (arg0.getSource()==browseSwing)
        onBrowseSwing();
        }});


Container container = getContentPane();
container.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
container.add(browseSwing);
container.add(textField);
container.add(approve);

//pack();
}

protected void onBrowseSwing() {
JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
int result = fileChooser.showDialog(this, "Open/Save");
if (result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
File file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
textField.setText(file.toString());
String x = file.toString();
fileRead(x);
}
}

public void fileRead(String input){
    try{
        // Open the file that is the first
        // command line parameter
        FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(input);
        // Get the object of DataInputStream
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        String strLine;
        int count = 0;
        int count2 = 0;
        //Read File Line By Line
        while((strLine = br.readLine())!= null ){
            if (strLine.trim().length() != 0){
                count++;
            }else{
                count2++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("-------Lines Of COdes-------");
        System.out.println("number of lines:" + count);
        System.out.println("number of blank lines:" + count2);
        //Close the input stream
        in.close();
        }catch (Exception e){//Catch exception if any
          System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }


}


public static void main(String[] args) {
new FileBrowse().setVisible(true);

}
}
```

but it chooses the individual files I want that all the files to be get selected inside that folder Test

Comment: I'd be use LineReader rathen than Scanner

Comment: @mKorbel could you please show it..!

Comment: [for example](http://java2s.com/Code/Java/File-Input-Output/LineNumberReader.htm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this code (adapted from [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/SelectadirectorywithaJFileChooser.htm)):

```
    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
    chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new java.io.File("."));
    chooser.setDialogTitle("choosertitle");
    chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
    chooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);

    if (chooser.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
    {

        Map<String, Integer> result = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        File directory = new File(choosers.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath()); //This is where you need to change.
        File[] files = directory.listFiles();
        for (File file : files)
        {
            if (file.isFile())
            {
                Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileReader(file));
                int lineCount = 0;
                try
                {
                    for (lineCount = 0; scanner.nextLine() != null; lineCount++)
                        ;
                } catch (NoSuchElementException e)
                {
                    result.put(file.getName(), lineCount);
                }
            }
        }

        for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : result.entrySet())
        {
            System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " ==> " + entry.getValue());
        }
    }
```

This code should replace this section:

```
Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter the Drive name like C,D,E etc");
String drive=in.next();
System.out.println("Enter the main folder name");
String main_folder=in.next();
File directory=new File(drive+":"+"//"+main_folder+"//");
```

Also, just a recommendation, when working with consoles and system paths, you should ideally use [`File.seperator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#separator). This will automatically provide you with the respective system's path separation character.

As per your edit, in your case you are using the `fileChooser.getSelectedFile();`. This will only get you the file that the user has selected, as per its name. What you should use is the `fileChooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath()` and iterate over the files which are within that same directory (as shown above).

EDIT 2: I use this code to display 2 buttons with their respective event handlers:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Button Sample");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JButton btnExit= new JButton("EXIT");    

        ActionListener actionListenerExitButton = new ActionListener() {
          @Override
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
            System.out.println("Exit Button Was Clicked");
          }
        };
        btnExit.addActionListener(actionListenerExitButton);

        JButton btnEnter = new JButton("ENTER");
        ActionListener actionListenerEnterButton = new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                System.out.println("Enter Button Was Clicked");
            }
        };
        btnEnter.addActionListener(actionListenerEnterButton);

        Container contentPane = frame.getContentPane();
        contentPane.add(btnExit, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        contentPane.add(btnEnter, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.setSize(300, 100);
        frame.setVisible(true);
      }
```

All that you need to do now is to plug in the code I have provided earlier in the appropriate event handler.

Comment: @npinti..thanks, it is able to select the test directory but it is not counting all the files , it is counting only one file inside that folder

Comment: @user1464381: Did you use the code I suggested or did you change your own?

Comment: yeah I have used the same code that you have suggested but still it is picking up pnly single file. please advise

Comment: @npinti..could you please advise what is not clicking

Comment: @user1464381: I made a mistake (haven't used Swing in a while), so my bad. I have fixed the error and it should work, at least it worked for me.

Comment: @npinti..thanks a lot it works , could you also please advise when I execute this application , it is by default when dialog box get opened it is in some other folder location by default , I want that upon execution it is by default in c: location , further user can navigate ,please advise how to achieve that

Comment: @user1464381: To change the starting directory all that you should need to do would be to change this line: `chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new java.io.File("."));` to something like `chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new java.io.File("C:" + File.seperator));`

Comment: @npinti..thanks a lot, it works ..ould you also please advise let say I want initially upon executing the application a main window should come with two button ENTER and EXIT , upon clicking the EXIT the application should end's up and upon clicking on ENTER the my application will open the dialog to select the folder as it is doing presently. what the main objective an main window with two buttons should com up first , please advise how to achiev that and integrate with the present application

Comment: @user1464381: What you need to do is to get a `JFrame` and display whatever `JButtons` you need. You should be able to find plenty of tutorials online. In the Event Handler for the Enter button, just paste the code I have provided. It should in turn show the `JFileChooser` and run the rest of the program. Note however that this will print to the console, not to the GUI. You could use a `JTextArea` to display the content.

Comment: @npinti..could you please show me how to achieve that..it will be a great help.

Comment: @user1464381: It is very similar to what you are doing. Like I said, you should be able to find all the help you need online.

Comment: @npinti..please if you could suggest some urls,since I am new to the world of swing, any how thanks a lot but if you could show that will be a great help, thanks in advance

Comment: @user1464381: Take a look [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/ButtonActionSample.htm). I doubt it can get easier than this. In your case, the event handler is the `actionPerformed` method.

Comment: @npinti..I am able to add the frame but not buttons ..JFrame frame = new JFrame("Frame in Java Swing");
    frame.setSize(400, 400);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

Comment: @user1464381: I have improved my answer. Please give it a look./